# chart error with EPPLUS

Tags: c#, excel, excel-2010, epplus

I have same problems when i créate a chart in Excel with epplus, i try to obtain something like this:
[image]

and the origin of the data:
[image]

and this is my code:

```
ExcelWorksheet hoja = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Grafico");
ExcelLineChart pieChart = hoja.Drawings.AddChart("crtExtensionsSize", eChartType.LineMarkers) as ExcelLineChart;

pieChart.SetPosition(1, 0, 1, 0);
pieChart.SetSize(800, 600);

pieChart.Series.Add("'hoja2'!$B$2:$B$" + listClienteVentas.Count + 1, "'hoja2'!P2:Q"+ listClienteVentas.Count+1);
pieChart.Title.Text = "Comparativa ventas";
pieChart.DataLabel.ShowCategory = true;
pieChart.Legend.Remove();
package.Save();
```

but this is the result:
[image]

and this is the origin of the data:[image]

What i´m doing wrong?

Comment: Seems like you want to add TWO separate series to the chart which would require two separate calls to `.Series.Add`.  See if this helps (Dual Axis option): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28540458/using-secondary-axis-for-chart-cause-x-axis-and-primary-y-axis-issue-excel/28547941#28547941

Comment: @Ernie Thanks you are right if i want 2 series i need 2 charts with the UseSecondaryAxis.