# Secondary Axis in Excel Graph

Tags: epplus

is it possible to set secondary axis in Excel graph using EPPlus code? If yes, could anyone please send an example? Thank you.

Comment: Can you specify the problem you're trying to solve, some sample data and maybe some code that you have tried?

Comment: You should post whatever code you have tried so far.  People are more likely to help.  See if this helps at all:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28540458/using-secondary-axis-for-chart-cause-x-axis-and-primary-y-axis-issue-excel/28547941#28547941