# How to add top line to stacked column chart in EPPlus

Tags: c#, excel, windows, epplus

I have a column stacked (bar) chart that relates percent (0-100%) as Y axis and a location on the X axis. Works fine. I would like to add a straight line at a fixed percentage (like 92%), possibly in red across the top horizontal. This would be an indicator if the location went below the 92% mark. This is a C# Windows VS 2017 solution with EPPlus.

Suggestions?

I am hoping I can only do this by drawing a line object that happens to lay on top of the graph, I don't think that would work if the user resizes the graph.

Comment: What id you did the old "fake" line trick: https://peltiertech.com/Excel/Charts/AddLineHorzSeries.html

Comment: That is an Excel solution. I am not using Excel. However, I will see if I can do the same but I have trouble combining two graph types together on the same graph.

Comment: It is an excel solution but Epplus is ultimately generating an excel file.  To add a second series see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28540458/using-secondary-axis-for-chart-cause-x-axis-and-primary-y-axis-issue-excel/28547941#28547941 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57500910/how-to-put-two-series-with-different-types-of-charts-inside-a-control-chart-usin/57516835#57516835