# epplus - how to add datavalue to secondary axix and remove some legend entries

Tags: asp.net, epplus

I am using epplus package in the asp.net c#.

1. how to add the data value to the secondary axis.
   (Note:ChartControl.DataLabel.ShowValue = true; - this is used to set it as primary axis data value)
2. How to remove some legend entries
   (No such legend entries from the legend class)

Note: Added Filler empty rows to put display it as stacked and unstackked chart in single chart

I followed the answer from the below link:
[Using secondary axis for chart cause x-axis and primary y-axis issue (Excel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28540458/using-secondary-axis-for-chart-cause-x-axis-and-primary-y-axis-issue-excel/28547941#28547941)

[image]

[image]

Comment: ok got it. i removed an urgent word from the question

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the code you have so far.  When you say, remove items, what do you mean exactly?  A good idea would be to post an image of what you want the final product to look like.